# Missing comments on enumeration members in sandcastle docs

Tags: documentation, sandcastle

I have noticed that my sandcastle documentation is missing any comment that was placed on enumeration member however the XML documents document produced by visual studio does contain the missing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Sandcastle Styles](http://sandcastlestyles.codeplex.com/) project.

Comment: Anything in particular that I should be looking at within that project?

Comment: Sandcastle June 2010 (2.6.10621.1) Patch - Rev 1 contains FixList.txt file which contains the following statement: Enumerated type members no longer contain a description in VS2005 style; Installing these styles solved the problem for me